# Changed Fstab file using gnome-disks utility, now stuck in login loop

Tags: 16.04, boot, mount, disk

I wanted to auto mount my hard disk on startup, and used the gnome disks utility - disk mount options and this changed the fstab file. I have separate root, home and swap partitions.

When I try to login now, i am stuck in a login loop. This is my current changed fstab file in /etc, got via tty.

[image]

What should I change now? I noticed that my home directory is empty now, (cd /home, where usually my user directory is present, making me think this is a mount Problem).
I do not remember the changes that were made to the fstab file.

Edit: output of sudo blkid
[image]

Edit: sudo lsblk[image]

Comment: It looks like you have deleted the /home line. Please update your question with th output of `lsudo sblk` and `sudo  blkid`.

Comment: Hi, I have also added sudo lsblk

Comment: I can login when i do sudo mount /dev/sdb3  /home, but i wonder if this is correct, and it is not permanent. The file system looks different than before (there is no drive called DATA in gui)

Comment: Put this in your /etc/fstab: `/dev/sdb3    /home   ext4  defaults   0  2`.  Eventually changing /dev/sdb3 with `UUID=the-uuid-for-sdb3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you somehow has deleted the line for /home in /etc/fstab.

`sudo lsblk` will show what partitions you have and their sizes, and `sudo blkid` their UUID.

Add the relevant partition to fstab like this:

`/dev/sdb3  /home  ext4  defaults  o  1`

or

`UUID=the-uuid-for-sdb3  /home  ext4  defaults  0  1`

The UUID way is preferred way because UUID don't change,but /dev/sdXY might if adding an other disk.